# UIPageViewController with previous and next buttons

Tags: swift

How to add previous and next buttons to UIPageViewController and only on button click the page should change with horizontal scroll effect. Can anyone suggest me any tutorial to refer?
As I am new to Swift, I don't know how to implement this. Please help..

Comment: is it required to make use of pageViewController if you want you can just make use of scrollView with multiplier values and get output

Comment: yes...PageviewController should be used.

Comment: do query is solved ?

Answer (score 0):

**Get next and previous UIViewController**

You should know what the current page and the previous page / next page are.

example:

```
@IBAction func onNext(btn:UIButton) {
    let currentVC = self
    let nextVC = getNextVC(from: currentVC)//implement it!
    // do stuff... (turn page)
}
```

**Turn page**

This is very simple, `UIPageViewController` provides such a function.

example:

```
pageViewController.setViewControllers([nextVC], direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. As Iam new to Swift, I don't know how to implement this. Can you please explain?

Answer (score 0):

here you can do it as using Buttons:

```
func addUIButton(){
        //next button 
        let myButton = UIButton()
        myButton.setTitle("Next", for: UIControlState.normal)
        myButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.red, for: .normal)
        myButton.frame = CGRect(x: self.view.frame.size.width - 50, y: self.view.frame.size.height/2 - 50, width: 50, height: 50)
        myButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(pagesViewController.pressed(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        self.view.addSubview(myButton)
        self.view.bringSubview(toFront: myButton)
    }
    func addSecondUIButton(){
        //previous button
        let myButton = UIButton()
        myButton.setTitle("Previous", for: UIControlState.normal)
        myButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.red, for: .normal)
        myButton.frame = CGRect(x: 20, y: self.view.frame.size.height/2 - 50, width: 100, height: 50)
        myButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(pagesViewController.Secondpressed(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        self.view.addSubview(myButton)
        self.view.bringSubview(toFront: myButton)
    }
```

Button handlers:

```
func pressed(sender: UIButton!) { //next button
        switch VC.CurrentVC {
        case page1:
            VC.CurrentVC = page2
            getNextVC(newIndex: page2)

            break
        case page2:
            VC.CurrentVC = page3
            getNextVC(newIndex: page3)

            break
        case page3:
            VC.CurrentVC = page1
            getNextVC(newIndex: page1)

            break
        default:
            VC.CurrentVC = page1
            getNextVC(newIndex: page1)

        }
    }
    func Secondpressed(sender: UIButton!) { //previous button
        switch VC.CurrentVC {
        case page1:
            VC.CurrentVC = page3
            getNextVC(newIndex: page3)

            break
        case page3:
            VC.CurrentVC = page2
            getNextVC(newIndex: page2)

            break
        case page2:
            VC.CurrentVC = page1
            getNextVC(newIndex: page1)

            break
        default:
            VC.CurrentVC = page1
            getNextVC(newIndex: page1)

        }
    }
```

Method that handles to move to nextVC

```
func getNextVC(newIndex: UIViewController){

        setViewControllers([newIndex], direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.forward, animated: false, completion: nil)
    }
```

Struct Class:
    //to store current vc

```
import Foundation

import UIKit

struct VC {
    static var CurrentVC = UIViewController()
}
```

Demo Project link - `https://drive.google.com/open?id=1pWLMcU2eny65zqdjxOMbnry2FwhkRjye`

For reference check this link

Output screenshot 
[image]